# taking File as a input in command line argument in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, openpyxl

I need to take Files as inputs from command line arguments. I am providing the path of the file but it is taking the path as filename ? What i can add to make it right . This is my code : I am using openpyxl to get names:

```
wk1 = openpyxl.load_workbook (sys.argv[1])
wk2 = openpyxl.load_workbook (sys.argv[2])
```

Please help out .

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. What do you mean "it's taking the path as filename"? Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No I want to take input the filename @Aran-Fey but when I am giving path of file , It is taking file path as file name

Comment: Can you show an example, any error messages, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to pass the file path in the command line,  So sys.argv[1] is receiving the file path, but  this syntax wk1 = openpyxl.load_workbook (sys.argv[1]) takes only filename as input , so when I giving th filepath it is taking it as file name , and I am getting  a error this file not found @cdarke

Comment: The phrase "file path" is confusing me, do you mean directory name?  If the API requires a filename then that's what you must supply.

Comment: Did you try using `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.exists` to check what python says about it? Maybe you should try providing an absolute path in order to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to have only filename even if argument value is a path.

This will do it

```
import os 
filename1 = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Yes that what I want @Eduard, but I have to check that this will work with my situation or not .

Comment: Thanks, @Eduard but I have the fourth argument also which tell the Directory where the output file to be stored, then how to write the path for it? I have written my code like this `output=sys.argv[3]    wb.save('%s.xlsx' %output)` which is creating output.xlsx file in the current directory but I want the file to be created at the directory given as in fourth argument.

Comment: @Deepraj that kind of operation an similarity are part os.path module. Just check docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path. Please mark answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: Hi @Eduard , Can you please tell which os module should I use to create a file in given file directory as arguments.

Comment: I will recommend going through a tutorial for file usage https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python and reading more advanced file/directory operations here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/filesys.html